# mysql avg value with specified number of rows

Tags: mysql

i have a simple table with
value (int), created (timestamp)

i would like to do a query that return an arbitrary number of rows with avg (value) and avg(created). The grouping function is the order by of created, means that if i ask for 2 rows, i should obtain a set based on the first rows ordered by created.

i have the following table:

```
create table  log(value int,created timestamp);

insert into log values
(1,'2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
(2,'2016-01-01 01:00:00'),
(3,'2016-01-01 02:00:00'),

(4,'2016-01-01 03:00:00'),
(5,'2016-01-01 04:00:00'),
(6,'2016-01-01 05:00:00'),

(7,'2016-01-01 06:00:00'),
(8,'2016-01-01 07:00:00'),
(9,'2016-01-01 08:00:00');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9a94

i want to retrive 3 rows that should be

```
2-2016-01-01 01:00:00
5-2016-01-01 04:00:00
8-2016-01-01 07:00:00
```

it's possible to do it in a single query without using java or php processing?

Comment: What determines the groupings?

Comment: Do you wish to average in groups of three ??

Comment: 3 is just an abritrary number, can be 10, 2.  The grouping is determined by the orderby on created column,  so if i put 10, i want to get avg(value) and avg(created) of the 10 rows, then other 10, then other 10 till the end of the results (order by created)

Comment: @sarathchandra yes, i think that that's it. The avg in a groups of N, but the order of created have to be respected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example when you group by 3, ordered by creation date. You can change 3 to the size you want to group by.

```
SELECT avg(sub.value), avg(sub.created)
from (
    SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,value, created 
    FROM log, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    ORDER BY created
) sub
group by floor((sub.row_number-1)/3)
```

---

#### UPDATE

if you always want it to be divided in 3 groups based on the number of rows you can do the following:

```
SELECT avg(sub.value), avg(sub.created)
from (
    SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, floor((@row_number-1)/c.num) groupid,value, created 
    FROM log, 
      (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t, 
      (SELECT ceil(COUNT(*)/3) num FROM log) c
     ORDER BY log.created
) sub
GROUP BY sub.groupid
```

Comment: it doesn't work, value isn't always ordered... it's just a random number

Comment: Ok now I think I get it. Changed it that way.

Comment: umm, it still doesn't work. Having more than 9 rows don't produce the expected results. 12 rows, should still return 3 row grouped, your example return more rows.

Comment: You can adjust the number 3 to whatever you want. For 12 rows you can take 4 for example. Or do you want to have this calculated automatically as well?

Comment: I've added how you can calculate it based on the number of rows. But I suggest that you edit your question as good as possible to what where we are now. So future readers will find this question as well.

Comment: for some reason that i don't get, the inner query executed alone, doesn't return keep the row_number correctly, thus the data isn't accurate. if i remove the count() and do it in another query, it work. i'll edit the description. Tnx